# Error in Latex on Windows 10 32 bits: Could not start the command

Tags: windows, latex

I have downloaded and installed (successfully) Texmaker on Windows 10.

When I try and compile a LaTeX file, I get the message:

```
Error: Could not start the command.
```

Could you help me?

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you. What does you LaTeX file look like and how exactly are you trying to parse the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install MiKTeX?
I recommend to install [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/download) on Windows

Answer (score 0):

I got "could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex" error while running Texmaker.

I checked Computer->properties->advanced settings->environment variables->PATH

and saw an unwanted quote (") at the beginning of MikTex path. Cleared it, problem solved. May not be a solution in your case.